# Dictionary definition for hyperlinks

Tags: shortcut-menu, dictionary

Normal Behavior: When highlighting a word on a webpage, and right clicking on it, a contextual menu pops up; you can get the dictionary definition by choosing, "Look Up 'SelectedWordHere'".

However, if the word you want a definition for is also a hyperlink there is no option in the contextual menu to look up the word in the dictionary. Any hints on how to get this to work? Without copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research it is possible to do this. The trick is to select the word/hyperlink but not right click directly on it. Right clicking to the side will bring up the correct contextual menu with the "Look Up 'word'" menu.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got access to a **multitouch trackpad**, tapping with **three** fingers will (if you've enabled the option under **System Preferences / Trackpad**, of course) directly popUp the definition of the word, even if it's an hyperlink.

Comment: I own a mouse...